# Can't Import .reg from SFX Archive

Tags: regedit

I can't seem to import .reg files unless I directly open them. I was making an sfx archive with WinRAR and I tried to make it silently import my .reg file but no matter what it refuses to do so. I made the archive run as admin, I verified regedit is able to find the file by removing the /s command line switch and even with the prompt it still doesn't import it. Something similar happened once when I tried running a .reg from Notepad++ with the RunMe plugin.

EDIT: Never mind, this seems to be an issue with the local security policy configuration. If anyone else encounters this bizarre issue try resetting it.

Comment: Please clarify what you are doing. Give an example `.reg` file and a screenshot of a cmd session where regedit is refusing to import it.

Comment: @harrymc I tried making a self extracting archive that would silently import/merge a .reg file. The problem is it doesn't unless I manually open the .reg and do it myself. I also don't get any errors. This seems to be a problem with other programs as well. Here's the [source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SN-HD8AWfxUF5DtL7doC6uS7NK1JmFz6).

I'm running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Can't use your example - Windows Defender immediately deletes it. Better [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1502395/edit) your post with the data of which product you are using and how.

Comment: I bypassed the delete. Which product are you using for creating the sfx and with what command? The file `oem_information.exe` is analyzed as a virus.

Comment: And your source is missing something. See [7Zip -sfx](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm).

Comment: @harrymc In the OP I said I use WinRAR not 7z. And I would suggest something other then Windows Defender, it's really bad. ESET doesn't flag it as malware. The .exe I provided are literally just the same two .reg and .bat files you can open it with 7z and verify for yourself. The problem is reg files don't merge unless manually opened.